# (DIFF EQ) Can functions be neither linearly dependent or independent over an interval? Confusing definition.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

This definition of linear independence of functions is very confusing to me because what if functions fit neither definition over an interval.

Like number 5 says it's linearly dependent, but I feel like that's only true for specific numbers of t, not for the whole interval.

Comment: How could functions "fit neither definition over an interval" since they are set to be dependent if some property P holds and independent if P does not hold?

Comment: @Did Technically the definition in the link is not phrased quite so directly as that, so a student not very comfortable with quantifiers might make this mistake.

Comment: @Did thank you! I understand the wording now, much appreciated.

Comment: @Ian I see where I went wrong. Thank you!

Comment: For the future: Please write complete questions without posting a photo

Comment: @Ian I beg to disagree. They even use two separate sentences. What would not be "so direct" here escapes me.

Comment: @Did It is not phrased as "a family is linearly independent if it is not linearly dependent", or something basically the same. They spell out what linear independence means, and maybe it's not obvious that this is just the negation of the previous definition.

Answer (score 1):

The functions from number 5 are linearly dependent because$$\color{red}{1}\times(t+1)+\color{red}{(-1)}\times(t^2+1)+\color{red}{1}\times(t^2-t)=0.$$Note the the numbers in red don't depend on $t$.

Comment: I misread the last one as t^2 - 1 hahaha. Thank you!